# Can't install qutip with anaconda in linux

Tags: python, anaconda, linux-mint, qutip

I have the latest anaconda version from linux 32. I'm trying to install qutip with the command

```
conda install qutip
```

but the package is missing. I already tried adding conda-forge channel.

Any idea of why the package is missing? According to the Qutip documentacion this should be a possible way to install the package.

```
Error message: 

Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - qutip

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-32
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-32
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-32
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Comment: can you show the error you are getting

Comment: I added the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we do not have linux32 builds on conda.  You can install via pip though, or build from source.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a channel to install from that includes your build architecture. The `conda-forge` channel only has `linux-64` builds: https://anaconda.org/search?q=qutip It doesn't look like there are any channels that support `linux-32`, but you can find the recipe for conda build here: https://github.com/conda-forge/qutip-feedstock, so you might be able to build your own package.